# To Access an Object from string Hierarchical Object

Tags: serialization, json-deserialization

I have a string object like this. I have tried deserializing using newtonsoft json converter but it results in the null object. I got to know the reason behind which is that the object I tried to convert to is inside the "data". Hence, it returns Null always for each property after conversion.

I want to know how I can access the "data" directly from this object?

```
{"data":{"providerRef":null,"orderId":"4579144","orderStatus":"x:app_pending","applicantInterfaceURL":"http://google.com","successful":true,"error":null,"reportAddress":null,"correlationId":"55f7022c-28f9-490a-8dd1-b30a40e3467a"},"status":0,"error":{"actionArguments":null,"errorCode":null,"errors":null,"message":null}}
```

Now, I have implemented it like [image]

The class **VolunteerBackgroundCheckResponse** have these properties:
[image]

Can anyone help me getting through the data object only from the json string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. I have used the JObject for the purpose and received all the properties beneath the main object. I accessed "data" and deserialized it.